# How to convert a XFIG picture to EPS for latex?

Tags: linux

I have generated a simple figure using a minimalist, powerful, XFIG software under Linux. I would like to display it into a LATEX document.

I thought good to export it to EPS, but this requires epstopdf and it is not compatible on Windows operating systems.

Is there any solutions to display this figure, with a good portability and universality (for any systems)?

```
#FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.6a
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4
100.00
Single
-2
1200 2
1 3 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 1 0.0000 4860 3510 2134 2134 4860 3510 6435 4950
2 4 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 7 0 0 5
         5760 4185 5760 2835 3915 2835 3915 4185 5760 4185
2 4 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 7 0 0 5
         2970 2205 2970 1395 900 1395 900 2205 2970 2205
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
         2025 4410 3330 4410 3330 3105 2025 3105 2025 4410
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think, `epstopdf` does not work on Windows systems? According to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf)  'the script is adapted to run both on Win­dows and on Unix-alike sys­tems.'

Comment: Why to EPS? Export as PDF directly.